# Edit .doc with OpenOffice

Tags: macos, openoffice

I have a word document (.doc) that I can open in OpenOffice, but can't edit it. How can I make this editable on a mac OSX?

Comment: What's the error message? Do you have write permissions to the file? Is it stored locally on your machine?

Comment: What do you *mean* by "can't edit"?  What happens when you try to edit the file?

Answer (score 1):

The file may be a password-protected read-only document.

From [How can I get an editable document from a read only document?](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/FAQ/General/How_can_I_get_an_editable_document_from_a_read_only_document%3F)

> If you press the "Edit File" button in
>   the toolbar while a read-only file is
>   open, you'll get an untitled copy of
>   the file to work with. When you try to
>   save the document you will be prompted
>   for a file name.

Comment: I have to do this occasionally at school when the professor gives us encrypted .docx documents.